# Need To Have Accordion Closed by Default

Tags: html, jekyll, accordion, netlify

I'm trying to close the accordion on the FAQ page by default.

It's a Jekyll site.

```html
<div class="nav-center pb-40 accordian-tab-menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills col-lg-12" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-general-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-general"
                role="tab" aria-controls="pills-general" aria-selected="true">General Issues</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-support-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-support" role="tab"
                aria-controls="pills-support" aria-selected="false">Support Issues</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-refund-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-refund" role="tab"
                aria-controls="pills-refund" aria-selected="false">Refund Issues</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to see where I can do it? Other suggestions re "collapsed" variable don't seem to work.

Edit - Adding additional code ...

```
<div id="accordion1">
                        {%- assign generalFaq = site.data.faq.issues | where:"category_name","general" -%}
                        {%- for faq in generalFaq -%}
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" id="generalHeadingOne">
                                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#generalCollapse{{ faq.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="generalCollapse{{ faq.id }}">
                                    <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    {{ faq.title }}
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <div id="generalCollapse{{ faq.id }}" class="collapse {% if forloop.index0 %}show{% endif %}" aria-labelledby="generalHeading{{ faq.id }}" data-parent="#accordion1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    {{ faq.description }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {%- endfor -%}
                     
                    </div>
```

Comment: What's your frontend CSS lib? [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), I guess?

Comment: Yes, it's Bootstrap.

Comment: I think you'll only need to remove the `active` class. Failing that, you may want to add `collapse`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Thanks Brad, I've played around with the collapse, accordion and aria controls ... no amount of combinations gets me what I want. Maybe I'll revisit it again when time permits.